# Replace "contains" with "add" in collections?

Tags: java, collections

I am using plain old `HashSet` implementation in my project.

I suppose that this code

```
if (!collection.contains(someId)) {
   collection.add(someId)
   // do smth
}
```

can be easily replaced with the following code

```
if (collection.add(someId)) {
   // do smth
}
```

WITHOUT ANY SIDE effect ? Am I right?

Comment: If you want to know that the item previously exists, it matters, otherwise not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `HashSet` (or any `Set` implementation) you are correct, both snippets are equivalent.

However, this is not true for any `Collection` (and since your title says `Replace “contains” with “add” in collections`, I thought it was worth mentioning). For example, `List`'s `add` always returns `true`, since `List`s allow duplicates. Therefore you can't replace `contains` with `add`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of HashMap, it replaces the old value with the new one.

In the case of HashSet, the item isn't inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, that will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Big Yes.

`if (collection.add(someId)) {
   // do smth
}`

This will work with `Set` implementations with no problems as they don't allows duplicate values, but will not with `List` implementations  as they allow duplicate items.